# How to synchronise a custom calendar to Apple calendar using PHP script?

Tags: php, calendar, icloud, icalendar

I am going to develop a website for an event management company. They need to list their events. Also they need a calendar and they need to synchronise that calendar to their Apple Calendar. That means need to generate a custom calendar (iCalendar or any other) and synchronise this calendar to their Apple Calendar automatically using PHP.
How it is possible? If it is possible, please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure they mean 'synchronise' (updates made either side) - that's hard.
Perhaps creating an ics url that they can subscribe to in their apple calendars is adequate?